# .git отслеживание файлов

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019, git-commit, commit

В какой-то момент заметила, что гит отслеживает все, абсолютно все файлы в которых я когда-либо работала, и сейчас этих изменений больше 7 000, как можно решить эту проблему? коммитить или пушить их куда-то я не планирую, т.к. файлы были для оттачивания практических заданий с курса. В гугле более-менее подходящее решение я для себя не нашла. Вдруг кто сталкивался с таким, прошу помочь.

Comment: Если гит там не нужен, то удалите папку `.git`

Comment: А что вы ожидаете в результате "решения проблемы"?

Comment: Создайте файл `.gitignore` и добавьте туда всё, что не нужно отслеживать гитом.